# MySql return xml attributes containing tag

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

Does the MySQL `ExtractValue()` method support XPath 'contains'?

I'm trying to return all attributes in the following xml that contain the string 'edit:'

```
<Data>
  <Row SomeAttribute="edit: return this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="not this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="or this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="edit: return this" />
</Data>
```

So I tried :

```
select ExtractValue(xml, '/Data/Row[contains(@SomeAttribute, 'edit:')]')
```

but it returns a query syntax error about the ' surrounding the string edit:

I also tried

```
select ExtractValue(xml, '/Data/Row[contains(@SomeAttribute, "edit:")]')
```

which just returns an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is, directly, not possible, but you can do something like this:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myproc`(IN `xml` varchar(400),IN `xpath` varchar(100), in f varchar(100))
BEGIN
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1;
   SELECT extractvalue(xml,concat('count(',replace(xpath,'[$i]',''),')')) into j ;
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp(i integer, x varchar(100));
   
   WHILE i <= j DO
      INSERT INTO temp SELECT i, ExtractValue(xml, `xpath`);
      SET i = i+1;
   END WHILE;
   SELECT * FROM temp where x like f;
END
```

and use it like:

```
SET @xml = '<Data>
  <Row SomeAttribute="edit: return this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="not this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="or this" />
  <Row SomeAttribute="edit: return this" />
</Data>';
call myproc(@xml,'//Row[$i]/@SomeAttribute','%edit:%');
+------+-------------------+
| i    | x                 |
+------+-------------------+
|    1 | edit: return this |
|    4 | edit: return this |
+------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You might need some changes according to your own needs (like the name of this procedure and the name of this temporary table)

BTW: the results are stored in the temporary table `temp`. So you can also do, after the stored procedure:

```
select * from temp where .....
```